# Solving Linear Systems with LU Decomposition and complete pivoting; stupid question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix A and vector B, solve

$Ax=B$

Using LU Decomposition with full Pivoting;

$PAQ=LU$

where P and Q are row and column permutation vectors (correct me if I'm wrong)

What I don't understand is what to do with the permutation matrices to finish the solution. I know in partial pivoting, its simple

$Lz=PB$

$Ux=z$

But what do I do with Q?

PS If anyone is a C head, you're help would be appreciated in the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695029/c-lu-complete-pivoting-decomposition-and-matrix-solver-something-isnt-right)

Comment: Remember that permutation matrices are orthogonal...

Comment: And since Q is the column permutation, and B is a single column, it can effectively be thrown away?

Comment: No; remember that in partial pivoting, the row permutation is "undone" by first permuting the right hand side. Undoing a column permutation corresponds to permuting the result after multiplying the RHS vector with the inverses of the triangular matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that permutation matrices have the property that $P^{-1} = P^T$, so we can re-arrange the factorization to write $A$ in the form $A = P^TLUQ^T$.  After that, it is straightforward to solve:

$\begin{align}
Lz &= Pb \\
Uy &= z \\
x &= Qy \\
\end{align}$

Note that $Q$ can't be just "ignored" because it is a "column permutation".  It is a column permutation by virtue of how it is used (right-multiplication), not by virtue of the structure of the matrix, and it *does* have an effect when applied to a column vector with left-multiplication.