# LU decomposition of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Although I know how the LU decomposition is done, given the following two matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
  0   & 2 & 3\\ 
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$ and $
\begin{pmatrix} 
  1     & 2 & 1 \\ 
  -2 & -1 & 1  \\
-2 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I would like to write them as **PAQ = LU** whereas P and Q are both permutation matrices and the decomposition is done with **complete pivoting**. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you just looking for the algorithm to do it?

Comment: yes, that would be great

Comment: Try [*Gaussian Elimination and LU-Decomposition by
Gary D. Knott*](http://www.civilized.com/files/gelim2.pdf)

Comment: I think specific answers are more helpfull for me, this is a 60 pages document.

Comment: You don't have to read the entire document - just search for the "complete" and get to the specific algorithm (less than 1 page). Regards

Comment: so for the first matrix I get: L = $\begin{pmatrix} 
  1   & 0 & 0\\ 
  6 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and for U I get $\begin{pmatrix} 
  9   & 8 & 7\\ 
  0 & 5 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ 

then for P = (3,2,1) and Q = (3,2,1). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$

Using complete pivoting for the decomposition, write $A$ as $PAQ = LU$ where $P$ and $Q$ are both permutation matrices.

Go slow and make sure you follow each step, as I cannot figure out an easier way to describe this and cannot find other examples from authors, so had to work this from scratch! Make sure you follow each step, great part is that the final table has all of the needed information in it and the algorithm is not bad once you go through it!

Lets write this matrix out in table form with the column-numbers in the top-most row and the row-numbers in the left-most column.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \end{array}$

Since $9$ is the largest magnitude, we want to swap Column 3 with Column 1 and also swap Row 3 with Row 1 to get that maximal value in the $a_{11}$ position. So, we now have (I show these column swaps in the top row of the table and the row swap in the left most column if the table).

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & 3 & 2 & 1\\ \hline 3 & 9 & 8 & 7 \\ 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\ \end{array}$

Now, we want to make the first element in Row 2 and in Row 3 to be zero, so we have (this is just Gaussian elimination in each of those rows using this maximal pivot value):

New Row 2: $m = \frac{6}{9} = \frac{2}{3} \rightarrow (6, 5, 4) - \frac{2}{3} (9, 8, 7) = (0, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{2}{3})$

New Row 3: $m = \frac{3}{9} = \frac{1}{3} \rightarrow (3, 2, 0) - \frac{1}{3} (9, 8, 7) = (0, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{7}{3})$

Lets rewrite our system with "all" of this data and continue the process, so we now have:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & 3 & 2 & 1\\ \hline 3 & 9 & 8 & 7 \\ 2 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{7}{3} \\ \end{array}$

Now we are working with the smaller $2x2$, which has a maximal magnitude value of $\frac{7}{3}$, so we want to swap Column 3 with Column 2 and Row 3 with Row 2. Lets rewrite our system to reflect these swaps (noting them in the top row and left column of the table).

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & 3 & 1 & 2\\ \hline 3 & 9 & 7 & 8 \\ 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{7}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ 2 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ \end{array}$

Now, we want to make the second element in Row 3 be zero, so we have (this is just Gaussian elimination in each of those rows using this maximal pivot value):

New Row 3: $\displaystyle m = \frac{-\frac{2}{3}}{-\frac{7}{3}}= \frac{2}{7} \rightarrow (-\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}) - \frac{2}{7} (-\frac{7}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}) = (0, -\frac{1}{7})$

We can now write our final system result and read off "all" of the needed matrices from this form!

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} & 3 & 1 & 2\\ \hline 3 & 9 & 7 & 8 \\ 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{7}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ 2 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{7} & -\frac{1}{7} \\ \end{array}$

We can now write $PAQ = LU$, using the previous table (everything is encoded into it)!

$P$ is formed by looking at the numbers in the left-most column $(3, 1, 2)^T$, which tell what row positions to put the $1's$ in our permutation matrix, so we have:

$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Of course, $A$ is just given.

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$

$Q$ is formed by looking at the numbers in the top-most row $(3, 1, 2)$, which tell what column positions to put the $1's$ in our permutation matrix, so we have:

$Q = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$L$ is just formed by making and lower-triangular matrix from the table and the Identity matrix as:

$L = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0 \\ \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{7} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$U$ is just formed by an upper-triangular matrix from the table and the Zero matrix as:

$U = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & 7 & 8\\ 0 & -\frac{7}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{7} \end{pmatrix}$

You can verify that indeed $PAQ = LU$ by multiplying both sides out and seeing that equate (plus you can see $A$ in there too.

Next question, how do use this to solve the original system? See this [*MSE response*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33474/solving-linear-systems-with-lu-decomposition-and-complete-pivoting-stupid-quest).

You can follow this example (go slowly) and do your second example.

Regards

Comment: @TestGuest: See my answer here above.

Comment: That was really, really helpful, thank you so much! Also the idea of "complete pivoting" became clear to me. A question for solving the second matrix now: For the first matrix, the maximal element (9) was unique, now for the second matrix, we have three elements with biggest maginute (namely two times -2 and once 2). Is it then unimportant which element of these three I pick first as maximal element?

Comment: Biggest magnitude means the biggest element in absolute value. So, |-7/3| was largest. However, what I would do if I came across two or more elements with equal magnitude is pick the first I came to (or look at the structure and see if you can figure out that it is better to choose another one as the pivot), but it shouldn't matter. Glad to have helped!

Comment: So, I am more or less done with the second matrix too. I just choose "2" as element with biggest magnitude and so got L = {{1,0,0},{1/2,1,0},{1/2,1,1}}, U ={{2,1,1},{0,-3/2,3/2},{0,0,0}}, P =  {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}} and Q = {{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}}. Two columns seem to be uncorrectly swapped if I do the necessary multiplications to check. Where is my error?

Comment: I cannot check until later -

Comment: The second matrix is singular. What does that mean?

Comment: Ok, checked your calculations and there are two issues. Both (1/2) terms in $L$ should be negative and then everything works out okay. Having said that - the decomposition works, but be careful because this matrix is singular - which, as you know, can have different implications.

Comment: What is the implication that the second matrix is singular? I know that singular most importantly means it is not invertible, and also it has not full rank. Also, another question: I am interested in knowing what the cost of this full pivot algorithm is. What is the *total* number of comparisons in abstract terms one has to do when applying this algorithm?

Comment: When the matrix is singular, you may or may not have solutions. The cost of this procedure is expensive (I do not have the stats) because you have to keep track of additional items when performing it, so people try to avoid it. Any good implementation will have a set of choices based on the matrix and figure out the best approach to use. From the things I read, this is one of the last choices given the additional storage and overhead. Regards

Comment: +1 for all the work!!!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, this was a fun method to get re-acquainted with!